# Event is not defined when trying to send data from service worker to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am trying to send data from my service worker to a react component but getting the error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

I have this code in my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', async () => {
    try {
        const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array('***')
        const options = { applicationServerKey,
                          userVisibleOnly: true }
        const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe(options)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error', err)
    }
    event.waitUntil(
        self.client.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then(clientsArr => {
            if(clientsArr[0]) {
                clientsArr[0].focus();
                clientsArr[0].postMessage({
                    msg: subscription
                });
            }
        })
    );
```

this is what I have in my react component:

```
useEffect(() => {
            ...
            if("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", message => {
                        console.log('serviceworker returns', message)
                })
            }
        },[]);

});
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to declare parameter?

```
self.addEventListener('activate', async event => {
// ...
```

Comment: I had tried this, got the same error